# What is the easiest/safest way to build my own Ethereum wallet (BIP44 HD)

Tags: ethereumjs, hd-wallets, bip39

I would like to build my own BIP-44 Hierarchical Deterministic wallet to store my ethers and to make transactions (receive/send). I'm not interested to use an wallet app. I don't care about the language, I'm just looking for the safer and easiest way to go: I'm not good at programming, but I could do it .

1. If Ethereumjs is the way to go, which ethereumjs package should I use?

   <strike>I have found from the [ethereum.org](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/programming-languages/javascript/) website the ethereumjs team. But there are several way to build a wallet with them, for example, one way is explained in this [tuto](https://medium.com/@harshagoli/so-you-want-to-build-an-ethereum-hd-wallet-cb2b7d7e4998) based on the individual [ethereumjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethereumjs-util) repo (that have been moved to [ethereumjs-monorepo](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-monorepo)) and another way is to use the [ethereumjs-wallet](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-wallet). Which is the safest way?</strike>

   *Edit: ethereumjs-wallet does not support signing transactions so it only leaves ethereumjs-monorepo for the ethereumjs-team. But it still leaved the second question.*
2. Or is there another way/package/programming language that is safer than ethereumjs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research, I went with [ethereumjs-util](https://github.com/cryptocoinjs/hdkey), [bip39](https://github.com/cryptocoinjs/hdkey) and [hdkey](https://github.com/cryptocoinjs/hdkey).

**A Installations**
Install [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) (npm will also be needed but it is included in node.js)

Then open a CMD and install the packages :
You can do it in 2 ways:
*Method A:* install via the `install @ethereumjs/tx` command. This will install the package in  `C:\Users\<iuser>\node_modules\` and you can access them directly in the Node command.

```
npm install ethereumjs-util  
npm install bip39  
npm install hdkey
```

*Method B*: install via a `npm install -g @ethereumjs/tx` command. It will install the package in `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`, then you will need to create a folder let's call it `folder_B` and inside of it another folder named `node_modules` and then run a command on `B` like `npm link @ethereumjs/tx` (cf below, for each package), and after that you will be able to use them in the Node when it is open on `folder_B`.

```
npm install -g ethereumjs-util  
npm install -g bip39  
npm install -g hdkey  


npm link ethereumjs-util  
npm link bip39  
npm link hdkey
```

**B Creating a mnemonic**
B1) preparing the environnement :
Open a cmd (if you use method A it can be started anywhere, if you use methob B it should started on `folder_B`)
Type `node` then press `Enter`
Once the node console is loaded (cf the message "welcome to node...), type:

```
bip39 = require('bip39');  
ethUtil = require('ethereumjs-util');  
hdkey = require('hdkey');
```

B2) generating the mnemonic

```
const mnemonic = bip39.generateMnemonic(256);
console.log( "mnemonic: ", mnemonic)
```

**C Deriving an address from a specific path in your wallet**
C1) If you still have the node console open from the Step B, you can continue to step C2, otherwise, first do the step B1 and save your mnemonic in a variable like this:

```
const mnemonic = "replace this by your mnemonic"
```

C2) From the mnemonic to the master private key

```
const seed = bip39.mnemonicToSeedSync(mnemonic);  
const root = hdkey.fromMasterSeed(seed);  
const masterPrivateKey = root.privateKey.toString('hex');
```

C3) From the path to the address

```
var path = "m/44'/60'/0'/0/0"  // change path   
var addrNode = root.derive(path);   
var pubKey = ethUtil.privateToPublic(addrNode._privateKey);  
var addr =  '0x' +  ethUtil.publicToAddress(pubKey).toString('hex');  
var address = ethUtil.toChecksumAddress(addr);  

console.log( "\n", "\n", "\n","ACCOUNT ", path, "\n", "private key : 0x", addrNode._privateKey.toString('hex'), "\n", "public key : ",pubKey.toString('hex'), "\n", "address : ", address)
```

C4) To get different address, you can rerun C3 with a different path each time, just change the last and/or third last number*. Some examples:

```
"m/44'/60'/0'/0/1"   
"m/44'/60'/0'/0/9"   
"m/44'/60'/1'/0/0"   
"m/44'/60'/7'/0/15"
```

- this is the meaning of the path (you only have to change the account and the address_index) : `m / purpose' / coin_type' / account' / change / address_index`

If you don't intent to use this wallet to hold real ETH, then you can verify the address, and the private/public key on for https://iancoleman.io/bip39/

**D Once you are done, delete nodejs history :**
In a CMD...

```
cd %userprofile%  
echo. > .node_repl_history
```

Or delete file : `C:\Users\<user>\.node_repl_history`